# Variable '$directions' cannot be non input type '[Step!]!' GraphQL apollo-client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js, faunadb

I'm a beginner at implementing gql so bare with any basic mistakes that might be the cause of this issue.

I have a mutation that is fired through a Netlify function towards FaunaDB that is returning the above error (Full error below). Making a query works in conjunction with the error make me believe that the issue lies with the

I've tried to define the typeDefs option in the apollo-client options and my client.js is currently looking like this after a few rounds of shotgun-debugging

```
const { API_URL } = require("./constants");
const fetch = require("cross-fetch");
require("dotenv").config();

const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Ingredient {
    name: String!
    amount: String!
    unit: String!
  }

  extend type Step {
    text: String!
    timer: Int!
  }
`;

const cleanTypeName = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  if (operation.variables) {
    const omitTypename = (key, value) => (key === "__typename" ? undefined : value);
    operation.variables = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(operation.variables), omitTypename);
  }
  return forward(operation).map((data) => {
    return data;
  });
});

const getClient = ({ method = "POST" } = {}) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      cleanTypeName,
      uri: API_URL,
      fetch,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET}`,
      },
      method,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false }),
    typeDefs,
  });
  return client;
};
module.exports = { getClient };
```

My Netlify function is looking like this

```
const { CREATE_RECIPE } = require("./utils/queries");
const { getClient } = require("./utils/client");
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    const client = getClient({ method: "PUT" });
    let { data } = await client.mutate({
      mutation: CREATE_RECIPE,
      variables: { ...JSON.parse(event.body) },
    });
    const result = data.createRecipe;
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };
  } catch (error) {
//return actual error for now
    throw error;
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify("Something went wrong while crating the cookbook. Try again later."),
    };
  }
};
```

and lastly the mutation is looking like this

```
const CREATE_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation CreateRecipe(
    $ownerid: ID!
    $cookbookid: [ID]!
    $name: String!
    $tags: [String]!
    $rating: Int!
    $categories: [String]!
    $images: [String]!
    $directions: [Step!]!
    $ingredients: [Ingredient!]!
  ) {
    createRecipe(
      data: {
        owner: { connect: $ownerid }
        cookbooks: { connect: $cookbookid }
        name: $name
        tags: $tags
        rating: $rating
        categories: $categories
        images: $images
        directions: $directions
        ingredients: $ingredients
      }
    ) {
      name
      owner {
        email
      }
    }
  }
```

The relevant schema.gql on the Fauna side is looking like this

```
  owner: User! @relation
  cookbooks: [Cookbook!]! @relation
  name: String!
  ingredients: [Ingredient!]!
  directions: [Step!]!
  tags: [String]!
  rating: Int!
  categories: [String]!
  images: [String]
}

type Ingredient @embeded {
  name: String!
  amount: String!
  unit: String!
}

type Step @embeded {
  text: String!
  timer: Int!
}
```

Edit: Full error

```
mutation CreateRecipe($ownerid: ID!, $cookbookid: [ID]!, $name: String!, $tags: [String]!, $rating: Int!, $categories: [String]!, $images: [String]!, $directions: [Step!]!, $ingredients: [Ingredient!]!) {
                                                                                                                                                                   ^
Variable '$ingredients' cannot be non input type '[Ingredient!]!'. (line 1, column 188):
mutation CreateRecipe($ownerid: ID!, $cookbookid: [ID]!, $name: String!, $tags: [String]!, $rating: Int!, $categories: [String]!, $images: [String]!, $directions: [Step!]!, $ingredients: [Ingredient!]!) {
                                                                                                                                                                                           ^
  ation CreateRecipe($ownerid: ID!, $cookbookid: [ID]!, $name: String!, $tags: [String]!, $rating: Int!, $categories: [String]!, $images: [String]!, $directions: [Step!]!, $ingredients: [Ingredient!]!) {
  
  iable '$ingredients' cannot be non input type '[Ingredient!]!'. (line 1, column 188):
  ation CreateRecipe($ownerid: ID!, $cookbookid: [ID]!, $name: String!, $tags: [String]!, $rating: Int!, $categories: [String]!, $images: [String]!, $directions: [Step!]!, $ingredients: [Ingredient!]!) {
  
  new ApolloError (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\@apollo\client\errors\errors.cjs.js:31:28)
  Object.next (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\@apollo\client\core\core.cjs.js:1043:53)
  notifySubscription (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js:135:18)
  onNotify (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js:179:3)
  SubscriptionObserver.next (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js:235:7)
  C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs.js:946:68
  Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  iterateObserversSafely (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs.js:946:25)
  Object.next (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs.js:1020:21)
  notifySubscription (C:\Users\phili\Documents\Projects\cookbook\node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js:135:18)
```

Comment: You should add your error message and explain how you get it in your question's body.
At first glance, it looks like `$directions` doesn't contain the expected type. Hard to debug further without more context. Take a look at https://github.com/Vadorequest/rwa-faunadb-reaflow-nextjs-magic it might teach you a few tricks regarding FQL/GQL :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link, I'll check it out! I also added the full error. It doesn't say much more which might be a reason I have such a hard time to debug it :)

Comment: read `input types` from `CreateRecipe` mutation specs/docs in playground ... it's always safer () to use 'main' `data` input type variable (pass one complex 'data' object in variables)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll take a look at that asap